# Почему значение из SQL автоматически комментируется на сайте?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Всем привет!

Записываю в БД языковую переменную для дальнейшего отображения на сайте.

Файл **model.php**

```
function login_history($username = NULL, $password = NULL)
{
             if ($username && $password)
        {
        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO login_history (
                                    ip,
                                    date,
                                    event,
                                    user,
                                    device
                            ) VALUES (
                                    " . $this->db->escape($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . ",
                                    '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "',
                                    '<?php echo lang(\'admin input available\'); ?>',
                                    " . $this->db->escape($username) . ",
                                    '" . $this->agent->agent_string() . "'
                            )
        ";
                    $this->db->query($sql);
                 }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Файл **view.php**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>IP adress</th>
      <th>Device</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($log_user->result() as $view) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td width="20%"><?php echo $view->date ?></td>
        <td width="20%"><?php echo $view->event ?></td>
        <td width="20%"><?php echo $view->ip ?></td>
        <td width="40%"><?php echo $view->device ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Все записывает нормально, но при отображении я получаю заккоментированный код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** почему это происходит и как избежать этого? Есть ли другие способы вывода языковой переменной?

Comment: Кто так делает то. Ну раз на то пошло передавайте только lang(\'admin input available\').А потом уже в выводе <td width="20%"><?php echo eval($view->event); ?></td> 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php

Comment: а чо функция lang(...) в этом отрезке кода нe доступна что вы eе во вьюхе исполняете ? если доступна то просто вызывайте ее вне кавычек 
VALUES (
                                    " . $this->db->escape($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . ",
                                    '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "',
                                    '". lang(\'admin input available\')."',
                                    " . $this->db->escape($username) . ",
                                    '" . $this->agent->agent_string() . "'
                            )

Answer (score 2):

> почему это происходит

`<?php echo lang('admin input available'); ?>` - этот PHP код Вы сохраняете в базе в виде строки и выводите во **view.php** с помощью `<?php echo $view->event ?>`. То есть, браузер получает этот PHP код в виде строки, определяет его как некорректный HTML и потому комментирует его.

> как избежать этого?

Пишите в базу само значение переменной, а не PHP код:

**model.php**

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO login_history (
                            ip,
                            date,
                            event,
                            user,
                            device
                    ) VALUES (
                            " . $this->db->escape($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . ",
                            '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "',
                            'admin input available',
                            " . $this->db->escape($username) . ",
                            '" . $this->agent->agent_string() . "'
                    )
";
```

А при выводе используйте `lang()`:

**view.php**

```
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $view->date ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo lang($view->event); ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $view->ip ?></td>
    <td width="40%"><?php echo $view->device ?></td>
```

---

Другой вариант решения проблемы (не самый лучший) - использовать 
[eval()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php):

**model.php**

```
$sql = "
    ...
  'echo lang(\'admin input available\');',
    ...
  ";
```

**view.php**

```
<td width="20%"><?php eval($view->event); ?></td>
```